# Data table that is searchable, filterable, sortable, orderable, exportable, server-side

Tags: sql, database, datatable

For work, I need a framework/library/plugin or set of tools that would provide a data table with the following features:

- Searchable
- Filterable
- Sortable
- Orderable
- Exportable (xls, csv, ..)
- Server-side processing (large datasets)

Our project is currently in rails, so preferably something that works well with it.

Bonus would be if there are data visualization features such as generating charts from the table data..

So far, I've considered DataTables, Handsontable, Superset,... but nothing checks all the boxes.

Answer (score 1):

Use 1.Pentaho Data integration tool

[Link about pentaho](https://www.hitachivantara.com/en-us/products/big-data-integration-analytics/pentaho-data-integration.html)

It has community and license version. You can use any of them